# NSOpenPanel stays open during debugging

Tags: xcode, cocoa, debugging, nsopenpanel

Is there a way to force the NSOpenPanel to close so I can see the screen while debugging? I can't see code behind it in Xcode while debugging and I can't move the panel either.

This is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)openImage:(id)sender {
    NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jpg", @"JPG", nil];

    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

            self.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:panel.URL];
            [panel close];


            [self doSomethingWithImage];

        }else{
        }
    }];
}

- (void) doSomethingWithImage {
    // if I put a breakpoint here, 
    // the NSOpenPanel is still on the screen and I can't move it.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to schedule `-doSomethingWithImage` on the main queue so the completion handler finishes (and the dialog closes) before `-doSomethingWithImage` is executed.

```
[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

        self.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:panel.URL];
        [panel close];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        [self doSomethingWithImage];

      });

    }else{
    }
}];
```

Comment: Did you set your breakpoint in the completion handler or in your main-queue-scheduled function (like -doSomethingWithImage)? Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found two approaches:

1. if you start your app, either move your app or `Xcode` to another desktop. So, when you run your app, it will jump to another desktop (where `Xcode` is located) when you reach a break point and the open panel does not get in the way with `Xcode`.
2. Use `beginSheetModalForWindow`: The coding is almost the same, but the panel does not hide parts of `Xcode` while you are debugging. `OpenPanel` is run as a choose panel related to a window. For `beginSheetModalForWindow` you must indicate the related window (usually the main window), which is the only additional coding needed.

Comment: I changed my panel to be displayed as a sheet and it fixed this issue for me.  Thanks!